# page method performance vs asynchronous http handler

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using several page methods that are currently in the code behind file. Basically, I receive a request, run a query, and return some json text; pretty classic stuff.
My question is this: if I move the page method into an http handler, will I see any performance or scalability benefit? What about using an asynchronous http handler?

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't speak to an actual performance difference, but know that an HttpHandler (.ashx) file is very light-weight compared to a Page (.aspx). For simple JSON calls, HttpHandler is my preference.

Comment: What's the difference in terms of performance and security between a custom http handler and a web service?

Comment: Well, the http handler is still lighter weight. A SOAP web service needs to encode the request and response in a fair bit of XML which adds to the payload.

Comment: I don't see any reason why it wouldn't.